# Liquibase - loadUpdateData complies CSV checksum changed

Tags: liquibase

I'm using loadUpdateData (also tried loadData) to load in a CSV file of static data into a table. Despite it being marked as runAlways="true", I get a checksum failure when I change the csv.

Liquibase maven plugin 3.5.2

**What I tried:**

I want to be able to change the data in the file (add/modify/dlete rows) and have the DB updated accordingly, so I've created a changeset to truncate the table and marked it  runAlways="true" and a changeset to run loadUpdateData which is also  runAlways="true". I don't want to have to resort to adding a changeset to delete from DatabaseChangeLog where the filename matches the one with these changesets. Is there another way ? runAlways seems to have worked for people on previous versions as per other SO posts and posts on the Liquibase site.

```
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.0.xsd
        http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd">

    <property name="now" value="sysdate" dbms="oracle" />

    <!-- Truncate the table and insert all the data from the CSV file -->
    <changeSet author="churcp3" id="deleteConfigData" runAlways="true">

        <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
            <tableExists tableName="CONFIGURATION" />
        </preConditions>

        <delete tableName="CONFIGURATION">
        </delete>

        <rollback />
    </changeSet>

    <changeSet author="churcp3" id="insertConfigData" runAlways="true">
        <loadUpdateData encoding="UTF-8"
            file="src/main/resources/data/configuration.tsv" quotchar=""
            primaryKey="CONFIGURATION_ID"
            separator="~" tableName="CONFIGURATION">
            <column name="CONFIGURATION_ID" type="NUMERIC" />
            <column name="SERVICE_NAME" type="STRING" />
            <column name="CATEGORY" type="STRING" />
            <column name="CONFIGURATION_KEY" type="STRING" />
            <column name="CONFIGURATION_VALUE" type="STRING" />
            <column name="CREATE_TS" type="DATETIME" />
            <column name="CREATED_BY" type="STRING" />
            <column name="UPDATED_TS" type="DATE" defaultValueComputed="${now}" />
            <column name="UPDATED_BY" type="STRING" />
        </loadUpdateData>

        <rollback>
            <delete tableName="configuration"></delete>
        </rollback>

    </changeSet>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

Answer (score 2):

Stupid me. It needs runOnChange="true"not runAlways="true".